# How do I access mounted secrets when using Google Cloud Run?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-secret-manager

I have two questions:

1. Why can't I mount two cloud secrets in the same directory?

   I have attempted to mount two secrets, `FIREBASE_AUTH_SERVICE_ACCOUNT` and `PURCHASE_VALIDATION_SERVICE_ACCOUNT` in the directory:

   `flask_app/src/services/firebase/service_accounts/`

   However I get this error, when attempting to do this:
   `spec.template.spec.containers[0].volume_mounts[1].mount_path, Duplicate volume mount paths are forbidden` Why is this?
2. How do I access a mounted secret using python?

   I'm really not sure how to do this as I couldn't find any documentation on how to actually access the secret itself. This is the only thing I [found](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/secrets). I am using python just for context. Would the secret be mounted as a .txt and is that mount path the folder that it is stored in or does it also specify the file name?

Comment: Please share the code or commands you're running

Answer (score 12, accepted):

With Cloud Run and Secret manager you can load a secret in 2 manners:

- Load a secret in a environment variable, use `--set-secrets=ENV_VAR_NAME=secretName:version`
- Load a secret in a file, use `--set-secrets=/path/to/file=secretName:version`

Therefore, you can read a secret as you read

- An environment variable (something like `os.getenv()`)
- A file (something like `fs.open('/path/to/file','r')`)

So, your first question about directory is not clear. If you mount 2 secrets in 2 files in the same directory, no problem!

If it doesn't solve your question, please, clarify.

Comment: Thanks! So referring to my second question when deploying a new revision, I specify a "mount path" which is `flask_app/src/services/firebase/service_accounts/` however I cannot add two secrets with the same mount path as this throws that error.

Comment: I tested with 2 secrets, in 2 different files, in the same directory and it worked well. You need to define an absolute file name, starting by `/` per secret. Add more detail on how you deploy if it still does not work.

Comment: thanks for taking the time to do that. I am using the GUI to deploy. This is the information I pass in: https://i.imgur.com/anFXHa8.png, the mount directory is the same for both secrets, however the path to the file is different so I don't understand why it gives this error: https://i.imgur.com/GUOfpwY.png

Comment: add a file name at the end of the path. Else, how will you read this secret in your code if both have the same absolute path name.

Comment: Unfortunately I have a similar scenario: if I use one secret it works. As soon as I add a second secret it does not work anymore. Non-functioning example:
  --update-secrets=/run/secrets/app1-credentials=serviceaccount-app1:latest,/run/secrets/app2-credentials=serviceaccount-app2:latest

Comment: Yes it is. It seems that Cloud Run does not allow two secrets mapped into the same folder structure. :( Probably a bug? It also seems a bit weird when I try to configure the secrets via Google Cloud GUI...

Comment: I tested with the CLI and it worked, not with the GUI

Comment: What am I doing wrong? gcloud beta run deploy awesome-app \
  --image=eu.gcr.io/awesome-project/awesome-app:1.0.0 \
  --platform=managed --region=europe-west1 --allow-unauthenticated \
  --service-account=cloudrun-secret-access@awesome-project.iam.gserviceaccount.com \
  --vpc-connector=vpc-default-network \
  --update-secrets=/run/secrets/app1-credentials=app1-credentials:latest,/run/secrets/app2-credentials=app2-credentials:latest

Comment: I found a way that works. It seems that Cloud Run somehow does not allow creating more than one secret file in exactly the same target folder, so I got it working this way: gcloud beta run deploy awesome-app \ --image=eu.gcr.io/awesome-project/awesome-app:1.0.0 \ --platform=managed --region=europe-west1 --allow-unauthenticated \ --service-account=cloudrun-secret-access@awesome-project.iam.gserviceaccount.com \ --vpc-connector=vpc-default-network \ --update-secrets=/run/secrets/app1-credentials/key=app1-credentials:latest,/run/secrets/app2-credentials/key=app2-credentials:latest

Comment: I too had issues with same dir for 2 secrets:

`--set-secrets=/etc/secrets/pgp_key_password=PGP_KEY_PASSWORD:latest,/etc/secrets/pgp_key=PGP_KEY:latest`

It only accepts the last of the list.

The UI does not fix it. The "show command line" button in the UI showed the same CLI commands I had tried already, so no help there. Finally, I tried to perform the deployment via the UI with my two secrets and hit this error:

`spec.template.spec.containers[0].volumeMounts[1].mountPath
Duplicate volume mount paths are forbidden`

Given the examples in the CLI docs I would say this is a bug.

Comment: The line `fs.open('/path/to/file','w')` will overwrite the file. I think you meant `"r"`.

Comment: I have my secret at `/secrets/admin` and I try and read from `/secrets/admin` but I keep getting not found

Comment: my problem was my build trigger was configured to use the inline cloudformation.yaml, not the repository cloudformation.yaml